# New employee entry: LDAP and Database Synchronization

Tags: database, database-design, ldap, database-connection

Here we are designing low-level business process for storing employees' details. (Another team deals with the higher level design). What we currently agree upon is this:

- We store employee's username, name, phone number, email, and the [plain-text] default password -among others- in an RDBMS (MySQL or SQL Server).
- This RDBMS ("DB"), the ssot of employee information, is exported to an LDAP system (OpenLDAP or Active Directory) which in turn becomes the primary authentication machine. The user's password is stored in the LDAP alone.
- A 'daemon' will be built to continually check the integrity between the two. It will check, say, every 2pm and report any anomaly found.

**First question**: does the above design reflect the best practice?

And what we currently seek is *a* design regarding data entry of a new employee (or editing an existing employee's information). One enters sufficient employee information through an interface  and when he/she clicks the "Submit" button:

- Option 1: a web service is invoked which will do two things: updating the DB entry and updating LDAP respective entry. Any error in either process will cancel the whole update operation.
- Option 2: a web service will update the entry in DB. This will then trigger a procedure that will export the updated record to the respective LDAP entry.
- Option 3: a web service will update the entry in DB. A batch process continually checks the integrity between DB and LDAP every hour, and if there's difference between both, it will update the LDAP with the DB as the source. In this option, one will get the message "Your updated information will take effect in 1 hour."

**Second question**: what's the best option? Are there any other common options we should consider? And what is the best -or commonest- practice?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep users in LDAP, as that's what it's designed for, and is good at it. Users can authenticate from many clients over LDAP.

I would use a database like Postgres, which has some LDAP integration.

a) Users can authenticate using LDAP

b) It has an LDAP [foreign data wrapper](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#ldap_fdw), which lets you query LDAP inside the database.

c) There is an already-built LDAP to Postgres sync tool:

https://github.com/larskanis/pg-ldap-sync

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever store plain text passwords! If you have to store passwords in the database, store the salted and hashed values.